# merging or extending partition

Tags: disk, disk-usage, partitioning

sda1 windows7 location...
sda5 ubuntu xenial location...
I want to merge the unallocated with sda5.
Drag to left option in sda5 is grayed out.

tried gparted live,unmounted all,but still no luck

Please guide me.

[image]

Comment: Ca you please post a screenshot of gparted showing your partitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to move and expand /dev/sda3 first, then you can expand /dev/sda5. You're using MBR / legacy BIOS, in which case you have to deal with something called "logical partitions". /dev/sda5 and above numbers are all labels associated with partitions contained within logical partitions. This logical container must be expanded first.

(For Windows 8+ users only) Also, consider disabling Power Options -> Choose what the power buttons do -> Change settings that are currently unavailable -> Fast Startup and Hibernation in Windows. This allows you to view Windows files from within Linux without any NTFS issues.

Comment: ok.i will try to move it.. I assume il move sda3 to the location of the unallocated.

Comment: @AaronFranke Your suspicions are correct. If there's no EFI partition then it must be MBR/BIOS. You can edit your answer and remove the "I suspect" entirely. The part about Windows is not correct as it doesn't apply to Windows 7, only to Windows 8 and newer.

Comment: @CelticWarrior You're correct, I've fixed my answer as per your recommendations.

Comment: moving /merging the said partition became frustrating..i just decided to format everything and start from scratch.thanks everyone